# The groovy script doesn't get list of aws images, What could be wrong?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, groovy

Here is part of code:

```
def ami_images_json = ["aws", "ec2", "describe-images", "--region", "us-east-2", "--owner", "1111111111", "--query", "Images[*].[Name]"]
// Parse JSON into Groovy object
def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ami_images_json.text)
// Prepare the results list
def ami_images = [];
data.each {
  for (String item: it) {
    ami_images.push(item)
  }
}
// Return the list for Jenkins "select-box"
return ami_images
```

I'm trying to get the list of images at the extended choice parameter.
However it gives me the error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String text
```

How to fix it?
Also I would highly appreciate if there is already a solution for this issue.
Regards.

**UPD:**
This one doesn't return values at extendet choise too:

```
def images_ls_output = sh(script: 'aws ec2 describe-images --query Images[*].[Name] --owner 1111111111 --region us-east-2 --output=text', returnStdout: true).trim()
def image = images_ls_output.tokenize().reverse()
return image
```

Comment: `text` property of `ami_images_json` does not exists, that is obvious. why would you parse a list of strings which is already parsed? you can iterate the list directly.

Comment: Are you intending to execute a command like `aws ec2 describe-images --region us-east-2 --owner 1111111111 --query Images[*].[Name]` and then parse a JSON response from that?

Comment: In first case you are not executing aws. I would choose the second case - but you have to provide more info. What aws command is returning if you run it from shell,  how would you like to transform the result. Otherwise it's almost impossible to help you.